# using find and delete files/folder - with the exception of 1 folder - challenging

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, script

i want to use find and delete everything with the exception of one folder if found.
e.g.

```
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 a
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 b
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 c
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 d
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 e
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 f
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall    0 Sep  2 02:05 g
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Aug  7 07:25 test2
```

I wanted to delete everything except test2.

So i started with

```
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ find test2 -prune -o -print
[oracle@SJOAM test]$
```

Return nothing.

q1) why isn't the above command without -name showing the rest of the files ? but with a "-name" shown below showing the rest of the files ?

```
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ find -name test2 -prune -o -print
.
./e
./a
./b
./d
./f
./g
./c
```

With -name , i can see the rest of the files. But i can still see the "." current folder.

```
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ find -name test2 -prune -o -exec rm -r '{}' \;
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Aug  7 07:25 test2
```

Well, all files are removed. But I kinda feel it is not the correct way -- it attempt to delete "."

q2) How to i prevent the delete of "." ?

Also,

```
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ find test2
test2
test2/a9
test2/a8
test2/a7
test2/a10
[oracle@SJOAM test]$ find -name test2
./test2
[oracle@SJOAM test]$
```

q3) Why -name is showing ./test  , but without -name, it is not showing the "./" ?

Comment: `rm *`. This won't delete test2 because it's a directory.

Comment: what if i wanted to delete directory also...other then test2

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
find . ! -name test2 ! -name . -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```

By adding `! -name ...`, we tell find to skip `.` and `test2` objects.

Answering to your first question, from `man find`:

> find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]

As you see, if you don't provide first options before the `[path...]`, find treats the first argument as a path to search in, so when you do `find test2 -prune -o -print`, it lists all files in the `test2` folder but reverses the output due to the *OR* statement ordered by -prune -o. This answer is related to your third question too.

Comment: what does ! means ?

Comment: `!` is a logical `not` operator. In this case it tells find to `not match filename`, when the default expression of -name is `match filename`